# Looking for a way to reverse engineer info.plist of an iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, reverse-engineering

I am looking for a way to programmatically retrieve permissions access (related to user's sensitive data) requested by an iOS app. For accessing sensitive information such as location, photos, camera, etc. app has to provide a description in the info.plist (key-value pair). So, my goal to retrieve the info.plist from app binaries and then study it to find out permissions information. Even an API that provides this information would also be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: jus unzip it and inside payload folder and the app name you find the info.plist

Comment: From where to download the zip file for iOS application source code?

Comment: in ios is not posible since your app only had access to it local bundle.